# Get the MAC address of a connected, unlabeled, unconfigured, unconfigurable ethernet device?

Tags: networking, ethernet, arp

Suppose you have some embedded board with ethernet plugged into the ethernet port on your laptop. You know nothing about it's network configuration (yet).  You know it boots, but it is headless and only has an ethernet port.  It does NOT have an ip address (yet).

How do you discover the MAC address of the device?

I've looked at arp, arping, arp-scan, arpwatch. The only thing I've found is using tshark and combing through the spew manually.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083014/get-only-the-source-mac-address-from-tcpdump

Answer (score 2):

Running plain `tshark` or `tcpdump` produces messy output, because all the traffic originating from your machine gets logged too.

Try

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -lenq 'ether src not <your_mac>'
```

- `-e` captures the ethernet frame too
- `-l` flushes stdout buffer immediately.
- `-n` don't resolve hostnames
- `-q` be more quiet.
- replace `<your_mac>` by the MAC address of your local interface as found with e.g `ip addr show`.
- obviously replace `eth0` with the correct interface. If you're on Windows, use `tshark -D` to list all interfaces.
- **(Edit)** On Linux you may use `tcpdump` instead of installing `tshark` which needs installation of the whole `wireshark` package. `tcpdump` should be pre-installed on Ubuntu (it's in the meta-package `ubuntu-standard`).

**Alternative:** If you want source MAC addresses as output only, do (inspired and shamelessly adapted by OPs comment below)

```
ETH=eth0;MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/$ETH/address); tcpdump -lenq -i $ETH "ether src not $MAC" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Best to start the capture without a link and then plug the cable in.

I don't think there is a way around sniffing traffic. The reason ARP fails, is that the device has no IP address and won't answer to ARP requests.

Another possible solution would be to connect the device to a managed switch and read out the MAC address table, but I feel that's not an option for you.

In any case, to be detectable, the device needs to send out *some* sort of Ethernet traffic. If you're lucky it sends a DHCP/Bootp discover which you can sniff.

**(Edit)** Why does the host not hold a MAC table like a switch does? Well, it doesn't need to, because it is not a switch. Unlike a switch the decision which interface puts out an Ethernet frame is made beforehand according to the routing table. The IP packet is wrapped in an appropriate frame after ARP lookup.

Sure, you can turn your machine into a proper L2 switch. You may create a bridge between multiple physical interfaces. I fiddled around with this a bit, and as it turns out you can get a nice MAC table that way!

1. Install `bridge-utils` from the repository.
2. Create a new Ethernet bridge in `/etc/network/interfaces`

   ```
    auto br0
    iface br0 inet static # dhcp goes as well
     address ...
     network ...
     bridge_ports eth0
     up /sbin/brctl setageing br0 300
     up /sbin/brctl stp br0 0
   ```

This defines a "bridge" (there's really no bridge - just one interface) without spanning-tree `stp br0 off`. Addresses will age out after 300s. Set this to your liking but not too low.

3. Bring the bridge up: `ifup br0`
4. Check if it's up with `brctl show` and view the MAC table:

   ```
    brctl showmacs br0
   ```
5. Profit (?)

Comment: Shouldn't there be a MAC address table somewhere in ~anything that uses ethernet?  Even if it's managed in the ethernet link layer hardware, seems like it should be exposed by the drivers somehow...

Comment: Also, why tcpdump instead of tshark?  Lighter weight? More mature?

Comment: He only recommended tcpdump as an alternative to tshark if you didn't want to install it. tcpdump comes preinstalled.

Comment: I tred a couple variations... ETH=eth1; read OURMAC </sys/class/net/$ETH/address; sudo tcpdump -i $ETH -e "ether src not $OURMAC" still spews stuff other than mac addresses

Comment: The tshark version isn't showing anything... ETH=eth1; read OURMAC </sys/class/net/$ETH/address; sudo tshark -i $ETH -Tfields -e 'ether src not $OURMAC'

Comment: @AndrewWagner Your command works for me! I've added a a modified version that gets rid of the "spew". Also, you can generate a MAC address table, by defining a bridge!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the deep answer!  I think each solution belongs in a separate answer though, right?  I actually hammered out my own toy packet sniffer for this; waiting for permission to open source it.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use wireshark to capture all traffic and filter it by bootp, or use `-e` option to print link-layer info and bootp filter with tcpdump:

http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html

```
sudo tcpdump -i any port bootps -e
```

Comment: Yeah... I'm just burning a lot of time trying to figure out right parameters  for tshark to make this happen...

Comment: sudo tshark -i eth1 -R bootp is giving me a bunch of "DHCP Discover" lines but no MAC...

Comment: @JoãoSilva please write a complete answer, don't give pieces in your comments.